# adaptive.js & LESS CSS compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, less

I am having an issue with [adaptive.js](http://adapt.960.gs/) and its compatibility with LESS. Problem being is that you cannot specify the type of document in the head because you have to include it via js.

```
<script>
    // Edit to suit your needs.
    var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
        // Where is your CSS?
        path: 'css/responsive/',

        // false = Only run once, when page first loads.
        // true = Change on window resize and page tilt.
        dynamic: true,

        // First range entry is the minimum.
        // Last range entry is the maximum.
        // Separate ranges by "to" keyword.
        range: [
            '0px    to 760px  = mobile.min.css',
            '760px  to 980px  = 720.min.css',
            '980px  to 3000px = 960.min.css',
        ]
    };
</script>
```

My question is that is there a way to be able to tell the adaptive.js that the files should be served up as less files so:

```
<script type="text/less">
```

rather than just:

```
<script type="text/stylesheet">
```

Or do I have to serve up the CSS server side prior to the adaptive.js taking effect?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why don't you just compile your less file? Not an answer, but a simple solution.

Comment: I think you meant to use `<link>` instead of `<script>` in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify adaptive.js by changing

```
css.rel = 'stylesheet';
```

to be

```
css.rel = 'stylesheet/less';
```

The final code should look like this:

```
var css = d.createElement('link');
css.rel = 'stylesheet/less';
css.media = 'screen';
```

Please note that you still need to reinitialize less.js again.

## UPDATE

I didn't know how to reinitialize less before but it looks like version 1.0.31 has a method: `less.refreshStyles()` which will re-compile  tags with type="text/less"

On your config add

```
callback: less.refreshStyles(),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this previously with text/less but didn't work. Cheers.

Comment: Works a gem. Now I just need to work out how to get less to import css on size adjustment. Thanks for your help.